# ES6 how to avoid nested functions

Tags: javascript

I have functions nested here in setTimeout

```
function startWorker (obj) {
  if (!code) {
    return setTimeout(2000, () => {
      startWorker(obj)
    });
  }

  console.log('worker started')
}
```

How do I correctly use startWorker as the callback without using more functions than needed.

What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to run the same function with the same argument as the callback to a setTimeout inside without duplicating function calls.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I don't understand, this is actual code.

Comment: Okay I have retracted my close vote but bear in mind this tip from [The Help center page _How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: Thank you, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but what if you just use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`?

```js
function startWorker(obj) {
  if (!code) {
    setInterval( () => {
      console.log(obj.action);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

const code = false;
const someObj = {
  action: "tick"
};

startWorker(someObj);
```